# Is there any way to use Backendless with tvOS?

Tags: parse-platform, tvos, backendless

I am trying to migrate from parse.com to Backendless. One of my apps was a new tvOS app and I am trying to get the Backendless API to work with tvOS, however it wont compile complaining that there are a lot of missing libraries (which is expected because the SDK isn't designed to work on tvOS). Is there any way to get Backendless to work with tvOS? Are there any 3rd party libraries I could try?

Answer (score 0):

Backendless provides [SDK for iOS, tvOS, watchOS and macOS](https://github.com/Backendless/ios-SDK). You can install it via CocoaPods. Add `pod 'Backendless'` to your Podfile. And don't forget to add a bridging header to your project if you use Swift.